# Расширенный поиск в firefox

Tags: регулярные-выражения, firefox

Кто-нибудь знает аддон для 9-й мозиллы, который встраивает в поиск поддержку regexp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если правильно понял вопрос, то либо

- [Fastest Search](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fastest-search/)
- [XUL/Migemo](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xulmigemo/)

Comment: Что-то похожее, но все равно не то, что хотелось бы. Тем не менее спасибо.